# Getting "Bad Request " as "Widget rfkid_7 not available" response in Sitecore Search API Explorer

Tags: sitecore-search

While exploring “API Explorer” in Sitecore Search, we always get an errors back with “Bad Request”. I would like to know what issue is causing for the “Bad Request”

```
{
    ""widgets"": [
        {
            ""rfk_id"": ""rfkid_7"",
            ""errors"": [
                {
                    ""message"": ""Widget rfkid_7 not available"",
                    ""code"": 102,
                    ""type"": ""bad_request"",
                    ""severity"": ""HIGH""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ""dt"": 140,
    ""ts"": 1674463655852
}
```

Where as I can see that i have the widget with the frkid_7 but it is still giving the this exception. Your help would greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Has the Widget been published?

Answer (score 0):

**"102 Bad Request"** error type corresponds with HTTP 400 and suggests that a request was not properly formed. So, please check your request and ensure that the latest "rfkid_7" widget version is published.

The below code sample illustrates how to create a simple request:

```
{
    "widget": {
        "items": [
            {
                "rfk_id": "rfkid_7",
                "entity": "content",
                "search": {
                    "content": {}
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "context": {
        "locale": {
            "country": "us",
            "language": "en"
        }
    }
}
```